# @RepositoryEventHandler events not invoked for Neo4j repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have written a RepositoryEventHandler to work with Spring Data Neo4j. I have tried many different ways of configuring this, but I can't seem to get any of the events to fire. The User data is successfully saved, but no log is generated, or breakpoint hit. I'm confident the @Beans are loaded due to some earlier errors generated during startup (missing libraries that I have since included).

The code and configurations are as follows...

The @RepositoryEventHandler:

```
package com.test.repository.handler;

@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class)
public class UserEventHandler {

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleBeforeSave(User user) {
        logger.debug("handle before save for " + user.getId());
    }

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleBeforeCreate(User user) {
        logger.debug("saved user " + user.getId());
    }

    @HandleAfterDelete
    public void handleAfterDelete(User user) {
        logger.debug("deleted user " + user.getId());
    }

}
```

The RepositoryConfiguration

```
package com.test.config;

@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    UserEventHandler userEventHandler() {
        return new UserEventHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    AnnotatedHandlerRepositoryEventListener repositoryEventListener() {
        return new AnnotatedHandlerRepositoryEventListener(
            "com.test.repository.handler");
    }

}
```

The UserRepository:

```
package com.test.repository;

public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

    User findById(Long id);
}
```

As I've looked for a solution to this problem, I have not come across anything that would suggest that the @RepositoryEventHandler would not work with Neo4j data repositories. Am I missing something?

Here are the relevant versions I'm working with:

```
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.2.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.2.1.RELEASE'               
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.2.1.RELEASE' 
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-repository:1.0.0.RELEASE'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:r05'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've the same issue. How did you solve yours? Can you post a link to your project, if it's on Github?

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating the userRepository "@RepositoryRestResource"
e.g

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
```

if those are the paths intended for users.

The handler methods should be invoked for rest calls against the rest repository, not just arbitrary crud calls within the app. For example if you create a bunch of users during app startup those inline calls will not invoke the handler.